# Finding a quote on the philosophy of love

Tags: reference-request, love

When I was a teenager I read a book which described a certain philosophy of love. Unfortunately I cannot remember the name of that book, but according to that book:

> *love is neither a feeling nor an action, it is just a state of mind.*

After so many years today I realized the meaning of the wordings written in the book.

Does anyone have the name of the book which I am referencing here? If so, please share it. I want to read it again, or any other book which describes the philosophy of love.

Comment: When I think of a 'philosopher of love' I immediately think of Kierkegaard.

Comment: That isn't really a lot of information to go on... Can you share more, for example the writing style?

Comment: Kierkegaard does have a text called *Works of Love*, and he does think love can be commanded and is understood through its works, but I don't recall any sentence suggesting it's a "state of mind" there. More importantly, *a lot of people* write about love and "state of mind" would be a common cliche and a contemporary one. It's going to be impossible to find this text with just this.

Answer (score 1):

I researched something of the sort a couple months ago, and found out that Schoppenhauer had some important considerations to give about the subject. He beat Charles Darwin on some suppositions about the parallel between humans - animals. You can find any information concerning those suppositions by reading *Die Welt als Wille und Vorstellung* by Arthur Schoppenhauer.

About love, exclusively, read *Metaphysics of the Love of the Sexes* by the same author. (Can be found here: http://www.uncharted.org/frownland/books/Schopenhauer/Schopenhauer_Love_of_the_sexes.html)